# Given a decently-sized dataset, what's the first step to start making predictions on it?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, training-data

So i got a database with 550k historical events in it.
For each event, I have a list of possible outcomes, and the actual result.

I want to use that to make some predictions about future events.

I have a general idea of how training works (theoretical), but I am completely new to the field.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose hard problem to start with.
I would start from NLP or Tabular models and going deep into it.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, better to start with something easier